# Getting infinite Json response when using many to one mapping in spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to create Many to one mapping between two entities in spring. However when I try to fetch the values using a restController I get

> Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the
>   response has been committed

error and an infinite JSON response. Adding JSON ignore solves this issue but then I don't get that column in my response at all. I don't know how to fix this. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl1")
public class Data {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "customer")
    private String customer;



    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="data_id", insertable = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private DataList dataList1;

}

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl2")
public class DataList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="data_id")
    private Long dataId;



    @Column(name="user_name")
    private String userName;



    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy = "dataList1")
    private List<Data> data1;


}
```

Repositories:

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface DataList extends JpaRepository<DataList,Long> {
}
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface Data extends JpaRepository<Data,Long> {
}
```

My error: `Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call sendError() after the response has been committed`

Comment: I'm not using any html.I was testing through postman.

Comment: Have you implemented your own toString methods or `@JsonSerialize` method? Are you using `lombok`?

Comment: I'm using lombok

Answer (score 0):

**1)** In general putting `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` on `@OneToMany` is not an advisable practice. Try to set it to LAZY instead.

**2)** Make sure that Data and DataList entities properly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

Comment: How can I check that they implement equals() and hashCode() properly.

Comment: What I meant is that you make sure they are implemented. Whether they are valid is for you to check

Comment: Yes they are implemented.

Comment: Is @Transactional on RestController method?

Comment: I'm using the default findAll() method that CRUD repository  provides.I've added @Transactional to my repositories.I've added the repos to my question.

Comment: I think those repositories as Transactional by default. Just want to make sure that there is no @Transactional defined somewhere up in the component hierarchy.

Comment: I'm not defining Transactional anywhere else in controller or model.

Comment: Try to give it a go with the LAZY config. Just make sure you fetch that dependency explicitly

Comment: Tried with Lazy config,still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening as JSON serializer is trying to serialize both the entities recursively again and again.

So, while serializing `Data`, its member `dataList1` is of type `DataList` which further contains `List<Data>`, this loop will be infinite.

Ideally, in such scenarios, the entities should be mapped to some other model meant for the serialization and response or one of the model needs to be `@JsonIgnore` to avoid this recursive loop going.

Comment: Adding @Json Ignore completely hides the response.I don't want that.

Comment: So, data contains data list and data list further contains data. Do you want this internal data variable as well?

Comment: I want that when I get Data List I should get the internal Data as well and when I get Data ,I should get that Data List as well.

Comment: when you talk about getting data from datalist and datalist from data. Are you talking about the java code or in the json response?

Comment: In the json response as I need to consume this response in a frontend app.

Comment: If I am getting you correct, then it is not possible to generate such a response.

Comment: JSON is a simple human-readable format used to transfer. In case of any object inside any programming language, it is possible because objects have reference of other objects, which avoids overflow for circular references. On the other hand in JSON, you have simple nested objects which do not have any notion of references, so if we want objects within object with circular reference, we will require a complete object and this will continue till infinity

Comment: I would suggest getting the response as a json with one level nesting only, load the json in your frontend and recreate the object structure you want to use by traversing and mapping them correctly. JSON is a format and it is not programming construct/variable/object as such.

Answer (score 0):

1. `EAGER` is a bad practice. Use `LAZY`, and when you need the related entities, use fetch join query.
2. Most likely the problem here in the bi-directional relation. You fetch `DataList` with `Data` list. And each `Data` in List `ListData` refers again.
   More likely here to be a stack overflow when serializing json. So remember one rule: **never give in controllers hibernate entities**. Write a mapper for map this entities to `Dto` objects.

You may think that it is extremely boring to map some models to another. But here in another way. Hibernate entities should not be passed to front end. My application uses several types of objects: `Entities` (when fetch from DB), `DTO` (When map entities to DTO and give their in service components), `Shared` (when map DTO to Shared and share as a response to the controller between my microservices) and `Model` (when map from Response to Model and give to the template engine, for example freemarker). You may not need this hierarchy of models.

Create DTO's:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class DataListDto {

    private Long dataId;
    private String userName;

    private List<DataDto> data1;


}

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class DataDto {

    private long id;
    private String customer;

}
```

write your mapper:

```
 public class DataListMapper {

    public static DataListDto mapToDto(DataList dataList) {
        return new DataListDto(dataList.getDataId(), dataList.getUserName(), dataList.getData1().stream().map(x -> DataListMapper.mapToDto(x).collect(Collectors.toList)))
    }

    public static DataDto mapToDto(Data data) {
        return new DataDto(data.getId(), data.getCustomer());
    }
}
```

your service:

```
public class DataListService {
            @Autowired
            private DataListRepository dataListRepository;


            public List<DataListDto> getAllData() {
                List<DataList> dataLists = this.dataListRepository.findAll();
                return dataLists.stream().map(x->DataListMapper.mapToDto(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to do this.

Comment: @rock11 i edit the answer.